# set value of child element from other element without using javascript

Tags: svg

I have this: hidden text element and line element. Line element change it's own opacity when cursor is over it. Also, text element  becomes visible when cursor is over line. Like this:

```
<text id="tooltip" x="75" y="5" font-size="3" visibility="hidden" stroke="none"  
    font-weight="bold"  fill="black">SomeText
</text>

<line id="myline" x1="10" y1="30" x2="30" y2="30" stroke-width="1" stroke="black">
    <set attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0.5"  begin="mouseover" end="mouseout"/>
    <set xlink:href="#tooltip" attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible"                  
    begin="myline.mouseover" end="myline.mouseout" />
</line>
```

Is it possible to change "SomeText" with some tag from within line element (like the way the visibility of text element is changed)? Note that I know how to do it with javascript, but I need clear svg code in this case.
More precisely: I want text element value to be set to "myline", instead of "Some Text", when cursor is over line element.

Answer (score 0):

SMIL only allows attributes to be animated. You'd have to have a different text element for each line I think.

Comment: I was looking for something like this to put in all line elements: <set xlink:href="#tooltip" attributeName="firstChild.data"  from="SomeText" to="myline" begin="myline.mouseover" end="myline.mouseout" />